# groupby([]) working with new variable but the new variable not displaying results in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get result of groupby([]) in Pandas.
Assigned a new variable to capture it.
No error and no result to display.
How can we get the new variable to display results ?

Code :

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('new.txt',sep='\t')
df2=df1.groupby(['name','age?'])
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0C7BA990>
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0D58B970>
```

Comment: What do you expect your result to be?

Comment: A `groupby()` on its own is not really a result, it's sort of a wrapper around the original dataframe. Once you actually use a method like `.mean()`, you get a result you can view. I guess if you want to see something, you can do `print(df2.head())`